# Vue 2 Prop value not rendering in the template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this code where I am trying to render a value from prop in the  template but getting a

> Uncaught ReferenceError: channel is not defined

```
<script>
    Vue.component('itemstable', {
        template: `<div>${channel}</div>`, // this is where the  error occurs.
        props: ['channel'],
        data() {
            return {

            }
        }
    })

    new Vue({
        el: '#items_app',
        data: {
            selectedChannel: 'pos',
            channels: JSON.parse(`["pos","kiosk"]`)
        }

    })
</script>
```

and here is the markup:

```
<div id="items_app">
    <itemstable
        :channel="selectedChannel"
    ></itemstable>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the name of the prop thinking 'channel' might be a reserve word, but the
same thing happens.

Comment: Try to move the `props` line above the `template` line.

Comment: didn't work. I have also put channel in data and removed from prop. still getting the same result. It must be something obvious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the javascript interpolation `${}` to vue expression `{{}}`

```
 template: `<div>{{channel}}</div>`,
```

Comment: Thanks.. knew it must be obvious.